# Routing in ASP.Net web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use a single RouteURL to route to different pages dependent on the Route name but when I click on a button within my aspx page the page gets routed back to itself:

Here is what I have in my Global.asax

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

Private Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As routecollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("1", "test", "~/default1.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("2", "test", "~/default2.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("3", "test", "~/default3.aspx")   
End Sub
```

And here is what I have put in my default1.aspx page:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.RedirectToRoute("2")
End Sub
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have duplicated your `routeUrl` values in your mapped routes. What's happening is that it *is* routing to your second route, as found by name "2", but that route is http://yoursite/test, which, when it then processes the request, is matching to the first route entry, or default1.aspx.

You can't use the same `routeUrl` (i.e., "test"), for all of your mappings.

Further reading: [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

An example of how you could change it:

```
Private Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As routecollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("2", "test/2", "~/default2.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("3", "test/3", "~/default3.aspx")   
        routes.MapPageRoute("1", "test/{*whatever}", "~/default1.aspx")
End Sub
```

Note in this example that route "1" is at the bottom.  This is because routes are matched top-down, so more restrictive matches should be listed first.  In this example yourdomain/test/2 will goto default2.aspx, yourdomain/test/3 will goto default3.aspx, and default1.aspx will essentially be the default, catching yourdomain/test, yourdomain/test/4, yourdomain/test/5, etc.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense.  Do you know the best way to achieve what I am trying to achieve though?  Is it possible to map the same routeurl to different pages?

Comment: It's not possible to match the exact same routeUrl. You would have to make some variation. I've added an example to my answer.